# SQL Server Agent configuration

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

Could anybody assist me on how could I possibly configure the SQL Server Agent for my local system (laptop)?

It doesn't appear under SSMS Object Explorer.

Been to the SQL Server Config Manager > SQL Server Services > SQL Server Agent > Properties... After that I'm confused.

Comment: Which Version Of SQL_SERVER You  Install

Comment: If you've installed an **Express** version of SQL Server, it's obvious: SQL Server **Express** does **NOT** include the SQL Server Agent ....

Answer (score 0):

First, as @marc_s mentioned in a comment, *"If you've installed an Express version of SQL Server, it's obvious: SQL Server Express does NOT include the SQL Server Agent"*

Otherwise, If you are not granted with needed permissions, SQL Agent will disappear, Whatever is the SQL Server Version

The role needed is `sysadmin`, or the individual roles listed here - [SQL Agent Fixed database Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent-fixed-database-roles)

Comment: I have 2012 Express edition.. so which edition do you suggest I mean provided it's available for free.. what configuration changes do I need to make?

Comment: Sql server 2016 developper (only 2016 not older versions) is free. Else you have to buy a standard or entreprise edition.

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/03/31/microsoft-sql-server-developer-edition-is-now-free/ it looks like 2014 dev version is also free

Comment: @AyushmanBasu if this is answer is what you are looking you have to [accept it](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)